# Why is GRANT not working in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I'm scratching my head on this one as I see a ton of helper websites showing how to create MySQL users and grant privileges but for some reason it just does not work for me.  I tried on both WinXP and a MacBook Pro laptop with the latest MySQL version installed.

The following is just an example from when I worked with WordPress.  The actual database is something different but same issues.

Here are the steps:

```
mysql> mysql -uroot -p<password>
mysql> CREATE DATABASE wwordpress;
mysql> CREATE USER 'www'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'basic';
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)

```
mysql> GRANT INSERT ON wordpress.* TO 'www'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'basic';
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User='www' \G
```

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 Host: localhost
                 User: www
             Password: *E85C94AF0F09C892339D31CF7570A970BCDC5805
          Select_priv: N
          Insert_priv: N
          Update_priv: N
          Delete_priv: N
          Create_priv: N
            Drop_priv: N
          Reload_priv: N
        Shutdown_priv: N
         Process_priv: N
            File_priv: N
           Grant_priv: N
      References_priv: N
           Index_priv: N
           Alter_priv: N
         Show_db_priv: N
           Super_priv: N
Create_tmp_table_priv: N
     Lock_tables_priv: N
         Execute_priv: N
      Repl_slave_priv: N
     Repl_client_priv: N
     Create_view_priv: N
       Show_view_priv: N
  Create_routine_priv: N
   Alter_routine_priv: N
     Create_user_priv: N
           Event_priv: N
         Trigger_priv: N
             ssl_type:
           ssl_cipher:
          x509_issuer:
         x509_subject:
        max_questions: 0
          max_updates: 0
      max_connections: 0
 max_user_connections: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As you can see "Insert_priv: N" should be "Y".

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

What you are selecting are the global privileges.
You are however giving database (and host, but that doesn't matter) specific privileges.

`GRANT INSERT` **`ON wordpress`**`.* TO 'www'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'basic';`

These permissions are stored in the `db` table.

Just to point you in the right direction:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'www'@'localhost'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html

Answer (score 16):

That's not where the most user GRANTed rights are stored - try

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'www'@'localhost'
```

to see database-specific permissions instead.  (A grant would only show up in the user table if it was for all databases.)

Here's a (rather old) step-by-step detail of [how permissions are stored](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3311731/An-introduction-to-MySQL-permissions.htm) in MySQL - I don't think things have changed much.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  However, I wonder what this table is for then?  I would think they should be consistent?  Here's one of many links showing that the fields should be 'Y': http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3A+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL

Comment: It appears RTFM is the answer here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html

Comment: @Christopher - I added a link that gives a discursive intro, hth.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I know it's an example, but it should be `database\_name`. You need to escape underscores because database names are pattern matches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at mysql.db or mysql.tables_priv tables if you need to select the Y or N if you are trying to do some restrictions of from what page a user can edit or insert or delete... This tables are automatically updated with the Ys and Ns as they are solely designed to show what privileges a user has on tables or columns as opposed to mysql.user whose purpose is to show that there is a certain user who can login(create connection) to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree I created 2 users and granted them all privileges on the database but somehow only one of the users will receive the upgraded privileges, no matter what I do the second user will not receive the privileges despite the fact that I tried to grant the privileges to the user in exactly the same way that worked with the first user and I flushed the privileges afterwards