# Mysql.User doesn't show all of the privileges

Tags: mysql, database-permissions

A colleague of mine had recently created a couple of mysql (v 5.6.x) users (test purposes only).
When I checked the mysql.user table, this is what I see:

```
mysql> select * from mysql.user;

+----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| Host           | User       | Password                                  | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | Create_tablespace_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections | plugin                | authentication_string | password_expired |
+----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
| localhost      | root       | ***************************************** | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |                       |                       | N                |
| 127.0.0.1      | root       | ***************************************** | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |                       |                       | Y                |
| ::1            | root       | ***************************************** | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |                       |                       | Y                |
| %              | readOnly   | ***************************************** | Y           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password |                       | N                |
| %              | complete   | ***************************************** | N           | N           | N           | N           | N           | N         | N           | N             | N            | N         | N          | N               | N          | N          | N            | N          | N                     | N                | N            | N               | N                | N                | N              | N                   | N                  | N                | N          | N            | N                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 | mysql_native_password |                       | N                |
+----------------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
```

Grants for the user **complete**

```
show grants for 'complete'@'%';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for complete@%                                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'complete'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****************************************'   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_db`.* TO 'complete'@'%'                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Grants for **root** on localhost

```
mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****************************************' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Question** : Why do all the privileges appear as **N** in case of the user **complete** when they should be **Y**? **root** also has all the privileges and they appear as **Y**. I checked, the user **complete** actually has all the permissions.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the permissions in the wrong place. This answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3893716/174184 gives me the answer. mysql.user stores the global permissions while the permissions were given only for a particular db.